# Holomorphic functions at $\Bbb C$ \ {$z_0$}

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, holomorphic-functions

The way i was taught, a function is holomorphic  in $z_0$ if it is (complex) differentiable in a neighborhood  of that point. However, holomorphic functions in C except $z_0$ are confusing me. Shouldn't the function be also holomorphic at $z_0$ if it is at all points on the neighborhood of $z_0$ ? What's incorrect on my thinking?

Comment: Take any rational function, then it will be holomorphic up to the zeroes of the denominator...

Comment: The function $1/z$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: I probably asked this the wrong way. I'm not arguing against the existence of holomomorphic functions in C \ {$z_0$}, quite the contrary, given that there are a million trivial functions which are holomorphic in C \ {$z_0$}. I'm just trying to understand why is that if a function is holomorphic in the neighborhood of every single point, except $z_0$, there isn't at least one of those neighborhoods containing $z_0$, making the function holomorphic at $z_0$.

Comment: Bascially you're asking why  $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_0\}$ is open. For any $a\ne z_0, $ consider the open disc $D(a,|a-z_0|).$

Comment: At first you have the definition of being complex differentiable at one point, then complex differentiable on an open $U$ which is the same as [holomorphic on $U$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the function be also holomorphic at $z_0$ if it is at all points on the neighborhood of $z_0$?

No, and for the following reason: the *sizes* of the neighbourhoods are not chosen in advance. Every point is differentiable on its own neighbourhood, and the size of that neighbourhood depends on the point we choose. In particular, since $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_{0}\}$ is open, we can always choose these neighbourhoods to be sufficiently small to exclude the point $z_{0}$.

For instance, $z \to \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. You might say "Well, it's holomorphic at $1/n$ for *every* $n$, so how could it fail to be holomorphic at $0$?". The answer is that we might only be able to guarantee differentiability at $1/n$ on an open ball of radius $1/n$, which then would not include $0$.

However, there is a theorem that comes to the rescue: if, in addition, your function $f$ is *bounded* on a neighbourhood of $z_{0}$, then there is an analytic continuation of $f$ to all of $\mathbb{C}$. That is, there is a holomorphic function $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which agrees with $f$ at every point in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_{0}\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I had been struggling with that a bit and just recently found out it was a missconception i had in the topology of the open set. Your answer cleared any doubts i still had left! :)

Comment: Fantastic, I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Holomorphic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_0\}$ are functions which are (complex) differentiable in every point of  $\mathbb C \setminus \{z_0\}$

Comment: I probably asked this the wrong way. I'm not arguing against the existence of holomomorphic functions in C \ {$z_0$}, quite the contrary, given that there are a million trivial functions which are holomorphic in C \ {$z_0$}. I'm just trying to understand why is that if a function is holomorphic in the neighborhood of every single point, except $z_0$, there isn't at least one of those neighborhoods containing $z_0$, making the function holomorphic at $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Then the answer is rather topological and the key point is "differentiable in a neighbourhood of that point" or ["some neighbourhood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function).

Let's take any $z^{*} \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_0\}$ Now, if we consider  $B_r(z^{*}, r)=\left\{  z \in \mathbb{C} | |z-z^{*}|<r \right\}$, i.e. centred in $z^{*}$ with radius $r=\frac{|z^{*}-z_0|}{2}$, this is an open disk containing $z^{*}$ and not containing $z_0$, which qualifies as "some neighbourhood".

Then, re "shouldn't the function be also holomorphic at $z_0$",

- first of all, the funaction may not be defined at $z_0$. Or
- as trivial as the function not being derivable at $z_0$, like there exists at least 2 sequences $\{z_n\}$ and $\{w_n\}$ such that $$\lim_{z_n \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-z_0} \ne \lim_{w_n \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(w_n)-f(z_0)}{w_n-z_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

See [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), whose main point is

> A holomorphic function $D \setminus \{z_0\} \to \mathbb C$ has a holomorphic extension to the whole of $D$ iff it is bounded near $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example you should spend time thinking about is $f(z)=1/z$. The function is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, as others have already pointed out. So, your question seems to be that if it is holomorphic at all points arbitrarily close to $0$, hence in neighborhoods of all these points, then why do none of these neighborhoods contain $0$?

Well, I guess the way you could think of that is just the Hausdorffness of $\Bbb{C}$. Given any point $z\neq0$, I can find a neighborhood of $U$ of $z$ which does not contain $0$. This will be our neighborhood of $z$ on which $f$ is holomorphic.

(Note in fact we didn't even need the complete Hausdorff property, just the fact that $\Bbb{C}$ is $T_1$)

If you have a specific follow up question, let me know and I'll try to answer it. Complex analysis feels very unintuitive to me in a lot of ways, so I understand how you feel

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my question and i then found out i was missunderstanding the concept of open set. I'm currently studying for a complex analysis exam and i'm searching for confusing concepts i had not comprehend earlier when i was introduced to all of this :D Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @JohnySilva no problem. Good luck on the exam